# IE: Ask via javascript for security settings

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

In IE 8, When I use

```
new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell")
```

to create an ActiveX object there will be a script error stating "Automation server can't create object". This is because the **wscript.shell is not secure for scripting** and in the default security zone the user is not even asked for execution. Is it possible  to **ask the IE via javascript for the ActiveX security settings** so that i can to avoid and handle the script error (and display a hint to the user?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always catch the error?

```
var shell;
try {
    shell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell") 
}
catch (e) {
    alert("You need to change your security settings")
}
```